# auto refresh and retrieve result from json

Tags: javascript, json, html

Here is my example I've two variables in Input.html file, I need to retrieve the variable in every second and assign the values into text box of index.html file., Help me where I'm doing the mistake..
I tried both ways..

```js
<!--or can I use this script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
       setInterval(function () {
           $.getJSON("input.html", function (data) {
               if (data.var1 == true) {
                   $('#Cycle1').val(result.trim());
               }
               if (data.var2 == true) {
                   $('#Cycle2').val(result.trim());
               }
           });
       }, 1000);
   });
</script>
```

```html
<!--input.html-->
{
"var1":"1"
"var2":"2"
}
<!--end of input.html-->

<!-- index.html-->
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="Cycle1"> 
    <input type="text" id="Cycle2"> 
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       setInterval(function () {
           $.getJSON("input.html", function (data) {
               if (data.var1 == true) {
                   document.getElementById('Cycle1').value = var1;
               }
               if (data.var2 == true) {
                   document.getElementById('Cycle2').value = var2;
               }
           });
       }, 1000);
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things missing from your second example. It looks like you're using the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) API for `$.getJSON`, so you'll need to be sure to include the library. You're also missing a closing `</script>` tag and attempting to use `var1` and `var2` as variables without declaring them first.

Outside of that, your snippet is nearly there. I would suggest though, instead of polling the server every 1 second, take a look into [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) :)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shccy08y/)

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
       setInterval(function () {
           $.getJSON('input.html', function (data) {
               if (data.var1) {
                   $('#Cycle1').val(data.var1);
               }
               if (data.var2) {
                   $('#Cycle2').val(data.var2);
               }
           });
       }, 1000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `code <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            setInterval(function () {
                $.get("Input.html", function (result) {
                    $('#counter').text(result.trim());
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>`this code has been run successfully with label in index.html,also Input.html file has only one letter that increments dynamically,I'm trying to do the same thing with multiple inputs in Input.html,also set the value in text boxes rather than labels in input.html

Comment: I've updated my example and included a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shccy08y/) of it working :)

Comment: I apply your logic in my module it is working fine in fiddle., but same thing not worked in browser, I could't understand this problem. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mmwfy9q/)  file of  my example. can you find out what is the problem?